# Not able to download file - The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

Tags: c#

I'm trying to download a zip file in Windows Application , but is is throwing an error . My code is :

```
    string url = "https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/DERIVATIVES/2017/JUN/fo07JUN2017bhav.csv.zip";
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.DownloadFile(url, @"c:\bhav\file.zip");
    }
```

Exception details :

> System.Net.WebException was unhandled   HResult=-2146233079
>   Message=The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
>   Source=System   StackTrace:
>          at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
>          at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(String address, String fileName)
>          at unzip.Form1.downloadFile() in c:\users\ethicpro\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\unzip\unzip\Form1.cs:line 30
>          at unzip.Form1..ctor() in c:\users\ethicpro\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\unzip\unzip\Form1.cs:line 20
>          at unzip.Program.Main() in c:\users\ethicpro\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\unzip\unzip\Program.cs:line 19
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.Run(Boolean checkAptModel)
>          at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.ExecuteAsAssembly()
>          at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext
>   activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
>          at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext
>   activationContext)
>          at System.Activator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:

Link is : https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/DERIVATIVES/2017/JUN/fo07JUN2017bhav.csv.zip

I searched for other questions but didn't get the proper answer.

Comment: Assuming the server is properly using response codes, this means you are not allowed. It probably has nothing to do with your code unless you are not supplying proper credentials.

Comment: Proper credentials including proper user agent, if they're blocking scraper-like code.

Comment: What other questions did you find? How are you providing your credentials? Can you download the file with your browser?

Comment: Works if you add a reasonable u/a: `wc.Headers.Add ("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.31 Safari/537.36");`

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks , it is working like a charm. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
string url = "https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/DERIVATIVES/2017/JUN/fo07JUN2017bhav.csv.zip";
        string fileName = @"C:\Temp\tt.zip";
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other"); 
            wc.DownloadFile(url, fileName);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks , It is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The file might no longer exist.
I use VB.Net.
But you have to use the equivalent of on error resume next on this file or another file with a more recent date with and without on error resume next.  Or the equivalent in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is that some characters cannot be downloaded, like `: | >` or .csv.zip should be .zip without the .csv.